# Lagrange interpolant

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation

Let $u_h$ be the $\mathbb{P}^k$ interpolant of some function $u$ (supposed smooth to simplify).
By definition, $u_h$ writes
    $u_h=\sum_i u_i \varphi_i$, where $u_i$ is the value of $u$ at the point $i$ and $\varphi_i$ is the Lagrange polynomial associated to the point $i$.

Now, if I suppose that I choose to use not $u_i$ as defined above, but $\tilde{u}_i$ some (random maybe) value such that $||u_i-\tilde{u}_i||=o(h^k)$ and so I construct the approximation
$\tilde{u}_h=\sum_i \tilde{u}_i \varphi_i$. The approximation $\tilde{u}_h$ is of the same order, but not interpolant.

Are there some situations where a non interpolant approximation like above (still using Lagrange basis functions) is preferred to the Lagrange interpolant ?

Comment: If you can use a non-interpolant approximation to remove spurious oscillations in the proper interpolant, then that is helpful...but this is not usually the way that you would do that.

Comment: Could you precise the way that it should be done ? From what I have seen, it is never used the way presented above, but usually with a change of basis (no more Lagrange), but I could not find the justifications.

Comment: It is mathematically the same to do it in some other basis vs. the Lagrange basis. Other bases are just better for certain reasons related only to numerical computation. But my comment can't really be realized without some context where you are seeing bad results from the direct interpolant.